# Huge disk usage on development virtual machine running Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, storage

I'm using Centos7 virtual machine as development enviroment, actually, to host my local server and project files. All development is done on windows 10 with virtual machine attached as network storage.

Now, the problem is that it reports huge disk usage on it, when inspecting one file (any file) that is <1MB, it says space on disk to be 1.00 MB, making project that are around 70 or 80MB use sometimes more than 2GB of disk space.

Any idea what could be causing this and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

More details: filesystem: NTFS, mixed projects including PHP, HTML, javascript (web and mobile apps using cordova) but I don't think how could programming languages affect this. Using apache2 as a web server. Protocol I don't have any idea. Virtualisation software is Oracle VirtualBox (latest).

Comment: Which filesystem do you use as network storage and what's the protocol? Also what are the virtual disk format and the virtualization software are you using?

Comment: So the development is done via a Windows client and the code is then built and run in the Centos environment? What stack is running n the Centos machine and what language are you developing in?

Comment: @RamanSailopal I have added more details to the question itself.

Comment: @bayindirh more details in question

Comment: How are you analysing the disk usage and what are you comparing it to in order to conclude that the space usage statistics are incorrect?

Comment: @Imaginaroom, so you're using an NTFS volume under Linux? If that's the case, please don't do that. Format the volume either with ext4 or xfs on the CentOS side, and mount the driva via NFS or Samba to the Windows. NTFS is not well-supported under CentOS

Comment: @RamanSailopal good question, I'm not comparing it, that's what windows is reporting this issue as I quickly ran out of space considering that I'm using it as a network attached storage.

Comment: @bayindirh I'm a newbie with linux, so I'm guessing you're completely right, will look into doing that. Thanks both. :)

Comment: @Imaginaroom To keep the question tidy, I'll write my comment is an answer, if that solves your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using an `NTFS` volume under Linux. If that's the case, please don't do that. Format the volume either with `ext4` or `xfs` on the CentOS side, and mount the driva via `NFS` or `Samba` to the Windows. NTFS is not well-supported under CentOS.

`NTFS` is not a primary filesystem for Linux in general, and it's supported via reverse-engineering in general.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use dynamically allocated virtual disks that may couse of unexpected disk performance issues.

Use fixed size virtual disks to best performance.

Try to convert your disks.

Comment: They are fixed size.